# is python str.split() inconsistent?

Tags: python, split, whitespace

```
>>> ".a string".split('.')
['', 'a string']

>>> "a .string".split('.')
['a ', 'string']

>>> "a string.".split('.')
['a string', '']

>>> "a ... string".split('.')
['a ', '', '', ' string']

>>> "a ..string".split('.')
['a ', '', 'string']

>>> 'this  is a test'.split(' ')
['this', '', 'is', 'a', 'test']

>>> 'this  is a test'.split()
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Why is `split()` different from `split(' ')` when the invoked string only have spaces as whitespaces?

Why `split('.')` splits `"..."` to `['','']`? `split()` does not consider an empty word between 2 separators...

The docs are clear about this (see @agf below), but I'd like to know why is this the chosen behaviour.

I have looked in the source code ([here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringlib/split.h?view=markup)) and thought line 136 should be just less than: ...`i < str_len`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the [`str.split` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), this behavior is specifically mentioned:

> If `sep` is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and
>   are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')`
>   returns `['1', '', '2']`). The sep argument may consist of multiple
>   characters (for example, `'1<>2<>3'.split('<>')` returns `['1', '2',
>   '3']`). Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns
>   `['']`.
>
> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, **a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace**. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

Python tries to do what you would expect. Most people not thinking too hard would probably expect

```
'1 2 3 4 '.split()
```

to return

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Think about splitting data where spaces have been used instead of tabs to create fixed-width columns -- if the data is different widths, there will be different number of spaces in each row.

There is often trailing whitespace at the end of a line that you can't see, and the default ignores it as well -- it gives you the answer you'd visually expect.

When it comes to the algorithm used when a delimiter is specified, think about a row in a CSV file:

```
1,,3
```

means there is data in the 1st and 3rd columns, and none in the second, so you would want

```
'1,,3'.split(',')
```

to return

```
['1', '', '3']
```

otherwise you wouldn't be able to tell what column each string came from.

Comment: Yeah. I've seen that and would add to the question. Do you know why is this the chosen behaviour? Some application/case for this behaviour?

Comment: @ijverig I've added a rationale to my answer.

Comment: I agree with you. What intrigues me is when separator is specified `split('sep')` doesn't do what "people would expect". And returning empty strings between consecutive separators is also very strange for me. I'd like to know if this is used in some popular specific situation. Thanks anyway, you were very helpful!

Comment: @ijverig The behavior fits my expectations quite well.  I expect splitting on whitespace to identify words in a piece of text.  Meanwhile, I'd expect `str.split(',')`, for example, to split a line of a CSV file nicely.  Essentially, split with no separator works well on natural language, and split with a specifier works well on data.  What I find somewhat odd is that they didn't just make this two different methods.